# how to get the value of list field type (check boxes)

Tags: theming, forms

```
$node=node_load(18);
$logo_img = file_create_url($node->field_site_logo[$node->language][0]['uri']); //origional image path
$show_logo = $node->field_options_site_logo['value']; //original image path
if(isset($logo_img)) {
  $web_logo = theme('image_style', array('path' => $node->field_site_logo[$node->language][0]['uri'], 'style_name' => 'site_logo'));
  print $web_logo;
}
```

I created CMS option of uploading site logo. I also added an option of show/hide this logo (form in node 18). Using the above code, I am able to load the image but don't know how to hide it if this option is not selected. I just want to know how to get the value of this check box. I can write the condition to show or hide this. Please help. Also, please let me know how to include alt option to the above image.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do you put this PHP code? If it's in the page.tpl.php, then you can use the `$logo`variable to display the field or not.

Otherwise, this configuration is available in your theme. So you need to get your theme configuration, with [theme_get_setting](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_get_setting/7). You should have a variable 'toggle_logo' or something like this. The full code would be

```
$test = theme_get_setting("toggle_logo");
if($test) {
   //Put your code here
}
```

If you're using different theme, or you need to get this value for a specific theme, then you need to pass your theme name as second parameter of the function, for example:

```
$test = theme_get_setting("toggle_logo", "my_custom_theme");
```

[EDIT FULL ANSWER]

So you just need to check the value of the field field_options_site_logo before outputing the image:

```
$node=node_load(18);
if(isset($node->field_options_site_logo['und'][0]['value']) && $node->field_options_site_logo['und'][0]['value'] == 'yes') {
  $logo_img = file_create_url($node->field_site_logo[$node->language][0]['uri']); //origional image path
  $show_logo = $node->field_options_site_logo['value']; //original image path
  if(isset($logo_img)) {
    $web_logo = theme('image_style', array('path' => $node->field_site_logo[$node->language][0]['uri'], 'style_name' => 'site_logo'));
    print $web_logo;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks Matt. 
Actually, my friend have trouble in changing logo image. So, I gave him an option of uploading it & option of hiding it in back-end. For this I created a content type (see image) There he can upload a image in and if he un-check the option to show logo in website, This logo images won't be visible in front-end. 
Now, I am able to print the logo using the above code but don't know how to check if the check-box is selected or deselected.

Comment: Suresh, you need to get the value of the custom field you created, something like `$node->field_other_options_show_logo["value"]` or something like this. If you're using the devel module, just use `dsm($node)` to see what is the path to access the field value.

Comment: I've uploaded the screenshot, which I got as output using dsm($node)